# ReclaiMe takes forever. Need a faster solution

Tags: raid, storage

Arrgh! I had a 4-drive RAID-5 array running nicely on an Intel DX58so motherboard until one of the drives gave up. No problem, right? That is why we use RAID-5, right?

Instead of alerting me and continuing to run on 3 drives, Rapid Storage decided the entire array should be declared FAILED. I've already replaced the bad drive, so it should be automatically rebuilt, right? Well, no.

When I run ReclaiMe, it grinds for over 20 hours before it tells me I have one missing drive and three good drives. I knew that. Then it reports the config matrix and gives me two choices: write the array to disk or write an image of the array to disk. I'm not sure that I understand the difference, but I don't have 20 hours to scan again and I certainly don't have 40 hours to wait while ReclaiMe grind out an image file. What I'd really like to do is get RAID to behave as it was designed.

What hardware can I buy that will accept the 3 good drives and make the array readable?

What hardware can I buy that might rebuild the 4th drive automatically?